# Using 2 or more needles when using strpos

Tags: php, strpos

Im running strpos on a `<a>` tag to see if it contains either one of two urls.

At the moment im using this bellow - how would i set it to check if - tumblr.com OR google.com were present ?

```
function find_excluded_url ($url) {

    $find = "tumblr.com"; // OR GOOGLE.COM ....

    $pos = strpos($url, $find);

    if ($pos === false) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}



// SET URL
   $url = "<a href='http://tumblr.com/my_post' rel='nofollow'>This site</a>";



// CALL FUNC
$run_url = find_excluded_url($url);

if ($run_url == true) {
    echo "URL - " . $url . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use two needles in strpos. But what you can do, is use it twice, with an or:

```
function find_excluded_url ($url) {
  return (strpos($url, "tumblr.com")!==false) || (strpos($url, "google.com")!==false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For more complicated searches, you might want to look into Regular Expressions. This would work:

```
$subject = 'blablabgoogle
  balblabtumblrasd
  blaasdgoogleadsad';

$pattern = '@(?:google\.com|tumblr\.com)@i';

$result = preg_match($pattern, $subject, $subpattern, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

if($result) echo 'Position: ' . $subpattern[0][1];
```

The performance of this (if performance is an issue for you) depends on how many search queries you have and how big your haystack is. Regular expressions come with a relatively big overhead, however, they only have to run over the text once. If you use `strpos` twice, this gets expensive with long strings. If performance is really an issue, you could also write your own strpos that goes character per character. I doubt, however, that this is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
function find_excluded_url ($url, $searchURL) {
    $pos = strpos($url, $searchURL);
    if ($pos === false) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

// SET URL
   $url = "<a href='http://tumblr.com/my_post' rel='nofollow'>This site</a>";

// CALL FUNC
$run_url = find_excluded_url($url, 'google.com');
if ($run_url == true)
    echo "URL - " . $url . "<br>";

$run_url = find_excluded_url($url, 'tumblr.com');
if ($run_url == true)
    echo "URL - " . $url . "<br>";
```